# C#: Monitoring Connections

Tags: c#, sql, ssl, sqlconnection

I am writing an application which has an `SslStream`/`NetworkStream`/`TcpClient` as well as multiple `SqlConnection` instances. I am sending and receiving data over them constantly, but as this is an application which accesses multiple servers both locally and remotely, I need to monitor the connections for failure and somehow attempt to restart them should they fail. Is there a Microsoft supported convention for how I should monitor these classes? The documentaton doesn't really show me anything. I've tried `CanRead`/`CanWrite` for the `SslStream` and I do, of course, have the ability to monitor timeouts. Is there a recommended time for timing these out? Is monitoring/counting timeouts the only way to monitor for connection loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed `SqlConnection` instances should be short lived. Only create them when you need them and then dispose them. Do not keep them hanging around in your application for when you want them, that is a very bad practice. The reason is that Sql Server (as well as other databases) implement connection pooling so creating the managed connection is relatively cheap as the underlying connection will be reused once its released back to the pool.

Comment: This is very helpful. The only problem is, this application will be receiving constant streams of packet data from a remote service, formatting them, and putting them into multiple SQL databases. How is this conventionally handled? If I open a new connection for every line I intend to insert, won't that get very connection intensive? Should I perform each insert on a different thread so I have tons of connections up at any given time?

Comment: @Rob - You could set up a queue (there are multiple Queue providers in .net) and structure it so that incoming data is pushed to a queue and then every XXX (some time frame) the queue is emptied by pushing the data to the database(s). In each execution where data read from the queue and written to the DBscreate a new SqlConnection for that time period and then dispose of it when the iteration completes.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, which is funny since I have so many other queues in my program already. Is there a good software rule-of-thumb for how often to handle a queue?

Comment: @Rob - it depends on the volume of data coming in and how fast you need to provide that back to the databases. *ie. If you only have one piece of data coming in every hour then no need to set your interval to every 1 minute*. Also consider using the timer `System.Threading.Timer` which is thread safe along with a thread safe queue implementation, then you don't have to worry about collisions between pushing to the queue and popping off the queue either.

Comment: This would be processing hundreds of transactions per minute, which I suppose is why I thought it best to not close the connection.

Comment: @Rob - Either way you approach it Sql Server can handle the connection pooling. You can batch transactions together for writing or not (do what ever you are doing now for that) but I would still create a new SqlConnection for each transaction as it is very cheap to do so. It also allows you to retry a transaction/transaction batch in your code without having to worry about transactions piling up (assuming you are multithreading) as you do not have to worry about a shared connection.

Comment: A FILO queue is inherently thread-safe for this operation, yes?

Comment: @Rob - check out the queues available in namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent` like ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentStack. These are all threadsafe.